# Classification of projective modules over polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

We know that the finitely generated projective $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$-modules, where $k$ is a field, are free; that's Quillen-Suslin theorem. But what about the not finitely generated projective modules? Actually, I find it already hard to come up with any non-free projective. Is there a classification of those? If not, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a paper of Bass "Big projective modules are free" (that [you can download here](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlid=10.1215%2Fijm%2F1255637479)) which answers this question in greater generality.

In this paper, it is shown in particular, if $R$ is a Noetherian connected ring (meaning $Spec(R)$ is connected), then projective $R$-modules which are not finitely generated are free.

This applies for example if $R$ is a Noetherian integral domain, and thus to any polynomial ring over a field.

Comment: Does that sense of connectedness relate to connectedness of graded $k$-algebras, i.e., $R_0 = k$?

Comment: $R$ is connected means that $Spec(R)$ is connected for the Zariski topology.